# Autoresize UICollectionView height to adjust to its content size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView, a button that creates a new cell in collection view. And I want UICollectionView to adjust it's size according to it's content size (when there are one or two cells then UICollectionView is short, if there are a lot of cell UICollectionView is big enough).

I know how to get content size:

`collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize`

But I have no idea where to use this value. I would appreciate if somebody help me to figure out how to make UICollectionView auto adjust it's height.

UPD:
I published on GitHub a demo project that describes the problem: https://github.com/avokin/PostViewer

Comment: Posted an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67055114/855680

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust height of UICollectionView to be the height of the content size of the UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437966/how-to-adjust-height-of-uicollectionview-to-be-the-height-of-the-content-size-of)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think content size is what you're after.  I think you're wanting to adjust the amount of screen real estate consumed by the collection view, right?  That's going to require adjustment of the frame.  The content size includes the off-screen (scrolling) area as well as the on screen view.

I don't know of anything that would prevent you from just changing the frame size on the fly:

```
collectionView.frame = CGRectMake (x,y,w,h);
[collectionView reloadData];
```

If I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: I have code like this: `cell.tagsCollection.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height);`. But before scrolling collectionView.frame height and width is 0 and iOS ignores my changes of these attributes

Comment: How to make cell height warp content

Answer (score 6):

Use a height constraint for the collection view and update its value with the content height when needed. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20829728/3414722

Answer (score 1):

You need to constrain the collection view height to the height of your content:

I'm using SnapKit in the following code.

First constrain the collection view edges to its superview:

```
private func constrainViews() {
    collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

    collectionView?.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        heightConstraint = make.height.equalTo(0).constraint
    }
}
```

Next calculate the height and set the height to the height constraint offset. I'm letting the flow layout do the work, and then calculating the height based on the bottom edge of the last layout attribute:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    guard
        let collectionView = collectionView,
        let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    else {
        return
    }

    let sectionInset = layout.sectionInset
    let contentInset = collectionView.contentInset

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: tags.count, section: 0)
    guard let attr = collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else {
        return
    }

    // Note sectionInset.top is already included in the frame's origin
    let totalHeight = attr.frame.origin.y + attr.frame.size.height
        + contentInset.top + contentInset.bottom
        + sectionInset.bottom

    heightConstraint?.update(offset: totalHeight)
}
```

Note that in the example, I always have one special tag not included in my items `tags` count, so the line:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: tags.count, section: 0)
```

would need to be something like `if items.count > 0 ... let indexPath = IndexPath(item: tags.count - 1, section: 0)` in most other code.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to change the UICollectionView frame:

1. Set the "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" property to YES  for the collectioview's superview (If you are using AUTOLAYOUT)
2. Then update the collectioview's frame as :

   ```
   collectionView.frame = CGRectMake (x,y,w,h);
   [collectionView reloadData];
   ```