# UICollectionView Auto Height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

i have a view with different subviews including a uiviewcollection, the thing is, i don't know how dynamically modify the uicollectionview height, the sizes of the cell is a fixed size, i'm just looking a way to figure out how make the uicollectionview height dynamic to show all the items, the number os items are not fixed.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: This did the trick and it was super easy to implement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20829728/5058757

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height constraint of UICollectionView.
Then Calculate your CollectionView height as per

```
(topSpacing + bottomSpacing + cellHeight) * number of cells (items)
```

then set heightConstraint again for your collectionview.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not working for me, i did it using  self.verticalConstraint.constant = self.uiCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize().height

Comment: Nope, its not like that you need to set height constraint of collectionview explicitly. Initially you can set anything.

When you get all cells data then calculate height like this:
CGFloat height = (cellTopSpacing + callBottomSpacing+ cellHeight (or content height)) * numberOfCells
then set collectionview.HeightConstraint.constant = height;