# Pass scroll between UIScrollView and embed UICollectionView

Tags: ios, scroll, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Here's my architecture.

I have a `UIScrollView` with some UIView's added in.
At the end on my scrollview i have a `UICollectionView` (embedded in my scrollview) in which i loads many data. I had to use a `UICollectionView` in order to reuse the multiple views displayed.

What i want is keep a **smooth scroll** when the user scrolls to the bottom of the parent scrollview and continue scrolling in the `UICollectionView`.

What i've made now is set the size of my `UICollectionView` equal to my `UIScrollView` Size and i've disabled bounces on both.

But i can't have a smooth scroll. When i reach the end of my `UIScrollView`, the scrollview's stop and then i have to re scroll on my `UICollectionView`

Not sure if it's really clear.

Answer (score 2):

You should not normally "pass scroll" between elements. What you need to make sure is that the `UICollectionView`'s frameSize is equal to its contentSize, meaning its frameSize expands as much as its contents so that all of its content is visible without having to scroll. Then your `UIScrollView` will handle the scroll and show the contents of your `UIViewController` by scrolling just itself.

Comment: By doing this i come really fast to memory warning because none of the UICollectionViewCell's are reused

Comment: Here it shows how to properly resize a UICollectionView so that it fully displays its contents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792299/uicollectionview-autosize-height/20829728#20829728

Comment: I've already implemented a similar solution, but by doing this, i can't reuse all the cells displayed i my collection view

Comment: this has nothing to do with reuse tho. collectionView should handle the reuse as some cells goes into the viewPort and some goes out. This approach is pretty common I would say.

Comment: if you update the frame of your collection view basing on the contentSize. How would you have a reuse ? There's has much cells has it need to fill the contentSize. So no reuse.
Let's say a cell size 50px in height and my UICollectionView's contentSize is 4000.
I'll have 80 cells instantiated at the same time. That's not a good solution

Comment: actually you are probably right about the reuse now that I tried myself. I never had to deal with 1000s of cells so never had to think about it... Then you might have to rethink your design of having 2 scrollViews inside each other or come up with a custom scrolling (probably paging) solution within your collectionView along with the solution I suggested.